# How can I permanently enable cheating?

Tags: deus-ex, cheats

I'm giving Deus Ex a quick playthrough as a refresher before jumping into Human Revolution. In the interest of expediency, I've decided to cheat. ^.^

Normally, cheats must be re-enabled for each level when playing the original DX. I've encountered instructions on several sites (word-for-word *identical* instructions, so clearly copy/pasted) for permanently enabling cheats, but they aren't working for me:

> Because you will need to redo this for every level, you can open up 'user.ini' and add 'bCheatsEnabled True' in the [DeusEx.DeusExGameInfo] section of the file to allow cheats to be activated forever.

Not only is that not working for me, it doesn't even *look* right compared to the rest of the file (space instead of `=`). With increasing desperation, I've tried adding that line (both verbatim and switching to an equal sign) to every section of both `User.ini` and `DeusEx.ini` which looks even *remotely* plausible — even creating a `[DeusEx.JCDentonMale]` section, just in case.

Does anyone know how to get this working? I'm running DX:GOTY version 1.112fm from Steam on Windows 7.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — Sorry for the rollback, but the question has nothing to do with Invisible War. That was just a bit of context. :-)

Comment: from your question it sounded like you were trying to enable cheats in *both* games. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Where is the user.ini file for steam users?

Comment: @xiao — It can be found at `%SteamDir%\steamapps\common\deus ex\System`, where `%SteamDir%` is the folder where Steam is installed (usually `C:\Program Files\Steam` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`).

Comment: What is this "invisible war" thing? There are only two Deus Ex games - the original and Human Revolution. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I wasn't able to get the `.ini`-based solution to work, there *is* another approach. Although billed as being for "earlier versions", the `-hax0r` switch works quite well with 1.112fm.

To add this switch to a Steam copy of the game, right-click it in your Library and select Properties from the menu. Click "Set launch options…" and type `-hax0r` into the text box. Click OK, then Close. From now on, when you launch the game via Steam, cheats will always be enabled.

If you're not using Steam, instead right-click on the shortcut you use to launch the game and select Properties. At the **end** of the Target box, add a space, then `-hax0r`. Click OK and you're done. Cheats will be enabled any time you launch the game via that shortcut.

Comment: what does "cheats will always be enabled" mean, though? if I run the game with this flag, there is no apparent way for me to pull up the "talk menu" to input any cheat codes.

Answer (score 0):

The .ini file for Deus Ex can be found at `%SteamDir%\steamapps\common\deus ex\System`, where `%SteamDir%` is the folder where Steam is installed (by default `C:\Program Files\Steam`).

Comment: I know where the files are, the problem is that editing them as described doesn't enable cheats.